# use a variable in python as string query to pass parameter in url

Tags: python, http, url

I want to use query strings to pass values through a URL. For example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key=xxxx&secret=xxxx
```

In Python, how can I add the variables to a URL? For example:

```
key = "xxxx"
secret = "xxxx"
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key=[WHAT_GOES_HERE]&secret=[WHAT_GOES_HERE]"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The safest way is to do the following:

```
import urllib

args = {"key": "xxxx", "secret": "yyyy"}
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?{}".format(urllib.urlencode(args))
```

You will want to make sure your values are url encoded.

The only characters that are safe to send non-encoded are [0-9a-zA-Z] and $-_.+!*'()

Everything else needs to be encoded.

For additional information read over page 2 of [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

Comment: after receiving url, how could you decode the args?

Comment: By doing an args{key} you can get it

Answer (score 4):

You mean this?

```
key = "xxxx"
secret = "xxxx"
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key=%s&secret=%s" % (key, secret)
```

Comment: Think about what the query string looks like when key = `abc&foo=1`.  The query string should always be encoded.

Answer (score 2):

concat your string and your variables:

```
key = "xxxx"
secret = "xxxx"
url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key="+key+"&secret="+secret
```

Answer (score 1):

I think use formatter is better(when you have many parameter, this is more clear than %s):

```
>>> key = "xxxx"
>>> secret = "xxxx"
>>> url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key={key}&secret={secret}".format(key=key, secret=secret)
>>> print(url)
http://127.0.0.1:5000/data?key=xxxx&secret=xxxx
```